# Ansys: issue with geometry visualisation

Tags: ansys

I am new to ansys and I am running ansys 17.1 on a macbook (on a parallel desktop) and I have a problem I can't solve. When I import or create a geometry, I can only see the silhouette of it in the "Study" tab (see picture 1). The contour results are not plotted either. When I try to edit the geometry instead, the part looks just fine (see picture 2).

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Picture 1:

[image]

Picture 2:
[image]